# Item in String-Array to hashmap in Android

Tags: java, android, listview, hashmap

i have a little problem im my project. I dont know how i can connect some item in String-Array to my hashmap.

```js
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
 private ListView lista;
    private String[] figury;

@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        lista = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView);
        opcjeListy();
    }
        private void opcjeListy(){

        Resources res = getResources();
        figury = res.getStringArray(R.array.figury);
        lista.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, figury));


            // Binding resources Array to ListAdapter

        lista.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View v, int pos, long id) {

                Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, kwadrat.class);
                intent.putExtra("figury", figury);
                    startActivity(intent);


            }
        });

    }
}
```

```js
HashMap<String, String> hm = new HashMap<>();
        hm.put("figury", "1");
tx.setText(String.valueOf(hm));
    }
```

```js
<resources>
    <string name="app_name">Geometria</string>

    <string-array name="figury">
        <item>Kwadrat</item>
        <item>Prostokąt</item>
    </string-array>
 </resources>
```

Finally i would create in MainActivity listview, and when i click in someone item, must open identified acitivity. 
I click X --> X activity.
I click Y --> Y activity.

Comment: What is the role of that hashmap? What exactly do you want to do?

Comment: Hashmap ? One people advised me this option.

Comment: I want click single item in listview and must open appropriate activity. When i click triangle in listview, i want open activity triangle.class. I click square, is opened square.class activity.